# Appending input form with name=string+javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm generating my javascript using PHP. I'm having problem when appending a form input. I can't use my strings and variable x as name. It failed to recognise the variable x, and treating it as a string.
This is what my code looks like

```
<?php
    foreach ($msgData as $key) 
    {
        $msgData .= ''.$key.': <input style=\\"width: 50px;\\" placeholder=\\" edit \\" name=\\"'.$nameArr[0].'-'.$nameArr[1].'-\'+ x +\'> ';
    }
    echo '
    function print(x) {
        wrapper=".name_fields_wrap";
        $(wrapper).append(\'<div>'.$msgData.'</div>\');
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
    var add_button  = $(".add_field_button");   
    var x = 3;
    $(add_button).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if ( x < max_fields)
        {
            print(x);
            x++;                                 
        }
    });
    ';

?>
```

My form name become:
**name= "nameZero-nameOne-'+x+'"**

Comment: This is a very bad way of writing code.. client side code should never be generated at server side.

Comment: why would someone like to do this like this?